# Way to differentiate between auto-save and regular save in office vsto add-ins

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office

I'm working with office vsto add-Ins c# and looking for a way to differentiate between auto-save and regular save events. As far I know, there doesn't exist a separate event for auto save. Based on the event type, I would like to have separate workflows. I find the documentation regarding auto save and vsto to be very minimal and couldn't find anything relevant. Any reference or a work around would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a whole Page on troubleshooting such problems on Microsofts Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/how-autosave-impacts-addins-and-macros)

Comment: @RobinB I have gone through them already, thanks. My specific requirement is to differentiate auto and regular save, may be a flag, which isn't provided out of the box as far I know. Looking for a workaround.

Comment: What is your final goal? Why do you need to differentiate them?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev In short, our workflow performs some actions on data on save, hit database etc. If its autosave, we want to suppress few actions and instead do them on a set interval so as to not bombard the database/UI experience since auto saves have short frequency. Hope this explains.

Comment: You must handle every change in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate save operations. For example, if another add-in calls the `Save` method and auto-save operations will be treated the same.

The best what you can do is to repurpose ribbon controls when the user clicks the save button on the Outlook UI. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overwhelm your backend with multiple requests, you can perform your DB operation only when the inspector where the item was edited is being closed and the item was modified.